# Confusion around Truffle, Ganache and Meta Mask

Tags: truffle, metamask, ganache

I am building a simple contract.

In truffle when I give 'truffle develop' command, I get following information:
[image]

On the Ganache, I have this:
[image]

And finally on Meta Mask, I see this:

[image]

**here, Shikhar is the custom RPC**

I think the network which 'truffle develop' shows is the one where my contract is getting compiled.

I am not able to figure out how can I sync the network and accounts in these 3.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like a very good idea to post your private keys and those 12 words on a public website.

Comment: This is just for testing. There are not of main network.

Comment: I think you can't do that in an easy way. You can always manually import each account you get from Ganache into Metamask, but note that the accounts in Ganache will change every time you start a new instance, so it's not practical. Ideally, you'd disable the Metamask plugin when testing with Ganache in your browser. And then you'd test your contracts with Javascript directly, instead of using Metamask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have 2 running blockchains.
The first one is developement blockchain spawned  by truffle and you can access its rpc using :

http://127.0.0.1:9545  as shown in your terminal

and the second one is ganache's chain which you can access its RPC using http://127.0.0.1:7545

If you are deploying your contract using Truffle look at `truffle.js` file

and then points Metamask to the chain you've configured there.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "5777"
    }
  }
};
```

once connected import the first account which indicated in truffle's console.

Comment: H, thanks for your comment. I think the problem lies with my limited knowledge of Blockchain technology.
I have further questions related to this.
1) I have only truffle-config.js file in the installed folder. is that the same as truffle.js file mentioned in your comment?
2) If I add the network in truffle-config.js file as you mentioned, then my smart contract will compile and deploy on that network right?
3) Is there any source using which I can better my understanding of these concepts?

Thanks :)

Comment: truffle-config.js is the same as truffle.js it's used normally in windows environment . 2-if you keep devlopment network yes but if you add more networks you have to specify which one are you using when you start truffle (truffle --network "network name") 3-https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration

Comment: @Shikhar if my response answer your question don't forget to mark it as accepted ;)